# Multiple Actions with one onclick event

Tags: javascript

I have a button that needs to do multiple actions.

First my button needs to move back one recordset within a file. Accomplished this. "skyWeb.recordset.movePrevious();"

Then if  the first file is reached and the user clicks the "Back" button it should move to the last file in the recordset (did this as well: "if (skyWeb.recordset.BOF) skyWeb.recordset.moveLast();") and then display a message that states it has reached the last record in the file. I can get the button to move to the last record but not display the message. Here is my code:

```
<button onclick="skyWeb.recordset.movePrevious(); if (skyWeb.recordset.BOF) skyWeb.recordset.moveLast() && alert('You have reached the end of file')">
                      &lt; Back
</button>
```

How do I get the button to both move to the EOF and display the message? I do not want to call a function but have the button itself do the actions.

Comment: Piling all this code into the HTML markup is considered a poor practice. You really should be bundling it into a function and calling that.

Answer (score 0):

You just don't need that "&&".

[Demo here](http://jsbin.com/welcome/27431/edit)

EDIT:

Agree with Michael Berkowski, you shouldn't use inline javascript.

Comment: I'm sorry. I know it is bad practice to use inline JavaScript. This is for an intro to XML class and I have yet to take JavaScript. So the use of a function is a little beyond my understanding as of yet. So, would the code then look like this?: <button onclick="skyWeb.recordset.movePrevious(); if {(skyWeb.recordset.BOF) skyWeb.recordset.moveLast() alert('You have reached the end of file')}">
                      &lt; Back
                   </button>

Comment: intro to XML class, you haven't taken JavaScript, but you are piling all that code onto an inline onclick? Yikes...

Comment: Even though you use inline JS, don't forget about semi-colons and brackets next to if statement, try this: http://jsbin.com/ejuloc/1/edit

Comment: Yeah, the way my program is structured I will take JavaScript next semester. I've looked at functions by googling them but I wouldn't know where to put the actual function that the button calls.

Comment: @Adaz thanks for the help. I know it's a mess but like I said, haven't taken JavaScript yet.

Comment: I'll have to get back to you tomorrow. For some reason my website does not work from home. It works fine from school, but not here. I'm not sure how that is possible.